# Internet Explorer 11 has null recordset

Tags: debugging, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, attachedbehaviors, forward-compatibility

I have a classic asp app that uses XML data binding. With the IE9 emulation setting it works fine up through version IE10. But in IE11, the recordset is always null. The values, however, are bound correctly to the input fields using #DATASRC and DATAFLD. It's just when I attempt to access a particular record via recordset.absolutePosition, it bombs.
Since data binding seems to be functioning, surely there must be a way  to specify a particular row of the data.

Answer (score 1):

The `datasrc` and `datafld` APIs have been [removed in IE11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625#legacyAPIs) partly for security reasons:

> Example:  The following use of data binding will result in the execution of script within IE:

```
<xml id=cdcat><note><to>%26lt;span style=x:exp<![CDATA[r]]>ession(alert(3))%26gt;hello%26lt;/span%26gt;</to></note></xml><table border=%221%22 datasrc=%22%23cdcat%22><tr><td><span datafld=%22to%22 DATAFORMATAS=html></span></td></tr></table>
```

> Note there is no SCRIPT tag present.  There are many similar obscure script execution techniques present in all browsers.

Use the following resources to create an alternative:

- [How to: Implement Property Change Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743695(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)
- [Migrating mutation and property change events to mutation observers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265032)
- [IE8 XSS Filter design philosophy in-depth](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dross/archive/2008/07/03/ie8-xss-filter-design-philosophy-in-depth.aspx)